# Return two dimensional array from function in c++ using matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I have created a matrix named "map" by using createMatrix() function. (I have used double pointed pointer because of the the structure have to be matrix). How can I return and use the returned matrix in the main function?

Comment: Hm you return matrix in createMatrix and you know how to access to elements so what the problem?

Comment: I want to reach the elements in the returned matrix.

Comment: fwiw, using the pointer-of-pointers when the row size is deterministic and the column count is fixed is overkill. Why not just `new int[2 * rowSize]` or perhaps `new int[rowSize][2]`? Why go alloc-happy when you don't need to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return the value by simply defining a double pointer in the main function.

```
int** p=createMatrix(N);
```

Now you have the return value of `createMatrix` function in `p`.

Comment: this method works. I can reach the elements by p[row][column].

Comment: be sure to check that p isn't NULL prior to accessing elements, as that will cause a segmentation fault.